# Hyper parameter tuning for Random cut forest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have used to below hyper parameters to train the model.

```
  rcf.set_hyperparameters(
        num_samples_per_tree=200,
        num_trees=250,
        feature_dim=1,
        eval_metrics =["accuracy", "precision_recall_fscore"])
```

is there any best way to choose the num_samples_per_tree and  num_trees parameters.

what are the best numbers for both num_samples_per_tree and num_trees.

Comment: For HPO you can use the tuning service of SageMaker: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sagemaker-automatic-model-tuning/

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                                                   Thanks a lot for your response, i have gone through the link that you have provided, but i didn't see any algorithm have been specified. i have pre-processed data stored in S3 location, can you please guide me how to proceed parameter tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are natural interpretations for these two hyper-parameters that can help you determine good starting approximations for HPO:

- `num_samples_per_tree` -- the reciprocal of this value approximates the density of anomalies in your data set/stream. For example, if you set this to `200` then the assumption is that approximately 0.5% of the data is anomalous. Try exploring your dataset to make an educated estimate.
- `num_trees` -- the more trees in your RCF model the less noise in scores. That is, if more trees are reporting that the input inference point is an anomaly then the point is much more likely to be an anomaly than if few trees suggest so.

The total number of points sampled from the input dataset is equal to `num_samples_per_tree * num_trees`. You should make sure that the input training set is at least this size.

*(Disclosure - I [helped create](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-built-in-amazon-sagemaker-random-cut-forest-algorithm-for-anomaly-detection/) SageMaker Random Cut Forest)*

Comment: Hi Chris,
i have trained the model and exposed the end point using AWS sagemaker.(taken best job based on hyper parameter tuning)
after inference, got some scores, based on third std deviation cut off ( mean+3*std),maked them as anomaly.
Now, the challenge is, how can we convience user wether it is really an anomaly or not.
i have applied some thing like, caluculate 3 rd std of each feature, if it is greater than original, i have treated as feature contributing to anomaly. apart from this , is there any best way to fig out,feature contribution to anomaly.

Comment: From what I understand you're asking about two things: (1) threshold determination and (2) feature attribution. Regarding (1): fitting a Gaussian distribution is a fine O(1) attempt but will likely lead to more false positives. Thresholding can be a difficult problem and it is very much dependent on the data. Regarding (2): while feature attribution in RCF is possible in theory the SageMaker implementation does not offer the necessary information.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response.i heard about RANDOM_CUT_FOREST_WITH_EXPLANATION will solve my problem.score explanation will try to give us the score of each attribute,after completing hyper parameter tuning,got a best model out of it and exposed end point based on best job name.can you please provide me any examples to get the RANDOM_CUT_FOREST_WITH_EXPLANATION with exposed endpoint. Once I have this,my problem will be solved.

Comment: The feature you're referring to is part of [Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sqlrf-random-cut-forest-with-explanation.html). As of this comment posting, this feature is not available in Amazon SageMaker RandomCutForest.

Comment: Hi chris, attribution is show stopper task now as after detecting anomaly if you could not able to tell end end user which attribute is causing the anomaly then it will be very difficult for end user to verify thousands of attributes,if you have any workaround or any solution,please let us know,could not afford KA as we have hundreds of models and not affordable 100’s kenesis stream

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any workaround solutions with SageMaker RCF. When it comes to recommendations on system design using AWS tools I'm not the right person to speak with. I suggest contacting an AWS Solutions Architect.